# Grouping certain rows in a column then repeat them in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pdb

I wish to repeat the rows from 11 to 17 many times, but I want that every repeat have +1 in column 'F' as you see in the desired dataframe. I thoght about Groupby() But I am not sure, which cretria I should pass to groupby() I want to have control over three columns.

```
     B     C    D  E  F  J
0    1    CM  MEG  A  1  C
1    2   HM1  MEG  A  1  H
2    3   HM2  MEG  A  1  H
3    4   HM3  MEG  A  1  H
4    5    OM  MEG  A  1  O
5    6    CA  MEG  A  1  C
6    7   HA1  MEG  A  1  H
7    8   HA2  MEG  A  1  H
8    9    CB  MEG  A  1  C
9   10   HB1  MEG  A  1  H
10  11   HB2  MEG  A  1  H
11  12   OEE   EG  A  2  O
12  13   CAE   EG  A  2  C
13  14  HA1E   EG  A  2  H
14  15  HA2E   EG  A  2  H
15  16   CBE   EG  A  2  C
16  17  HB1E   EG  A  2  H
17  18  HB2E   EG  A  2  H
18  19    OE  EGH  A  3  O
19  20    CA  EGH  A  3  C
20  21   HA1  EGH  A  3  H
21  22   HA2  EGH  A  3  H
22  23    CB  EGH  A  3  C
23  24   HB1  EGH  A  3  H
24  25   HB2  EGH  A  3  H
```

DISIRED DATAFRAME:

```
   B     C    D  E  F  J
0    1    CM  MEG  A  1  C
1    2   HM1  MEG  A  1  H
2    3   HM2  MEG  A  1  H
3    4   HM3  MEG  A  1  H
4    5    OM  MEG  A  1  O
5    6    CA  MEG  A  1  C
6    7   HA1  MEG  A  1  H
7    8   HA2  MEG  A  1  H
8    9    CB  MEG  A  1  C
9   10   HB1  MEG  A  1  H
10  11   HB2  MEG  A  1  H
11  12   OE   EG  A  2  O
12  13   CA   EG  A  2  C
13  14  HA1   EG  A  2  H
14  15  HA2   EG  A  2  H
15  16   CB   EG  A  2  C
16  17  HB1   EG  A  2  H
17  18  HB2   EG  A  2  H

18  19   OE   EG  A  3  O
19  20   CA   EG  A  3  C
20  21  HA1   EG  A  3  H
21  22  HA2   EG  A  3  H
22  23   CB   EG  A  3  C
23  24  HB1   EG  A  3  H
24  25  HB2   EG  A  3  H

25  26   OE   EG  A  4  O
26  27   CA   EG  A  4  C
27  28  HA1   EG  A  4  H
28  29  HA2   EG  A  4  H
29  30   CB   EG  A  4  C
30  31  HB1   EG  A  4  H
31  32  HB2   EG  A  4  H

32  33    OE  EGH  A  5  O
33  34    CA  EGH  A  5  C
34  35   HA1  EGH  A  5  H
35  36   HA2  EGH  A  5  H
36  37    CB  EGH  A  5  C
37  38   HB1  EGH  A  5  H
38  39   HB2  EGH  A  5  H
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
start = 11
stop  = 17
repeat = 3

d = df.iloc[start:stop+1]

pd.concat([df.iloc[:start]]+
          [d.assign(F=d['F']+i) for i in range(repeat)]+
          [df.iloc[stop:]], ignore_index=True
         )
```

output:

```
     B     C    D  E  F  J
0    1    CM  MEG  A  1  C
1    2   HM1  MEG  A  1  H
2    3   HM2  MEG  A  1  H
3    4   HM3  MEG  A  1  H
4    5    OM  MEG  A  1  O
5    6    CA  MEG  A  1  C
6    7   HA1  MEG  A  1  H
7    8   HA2  MEG  A  1  H
8    9    CB  MEG  A  1  C
9   10   HB1  MEG  A  1  H
10  11   HB2  MEG  A  1  H
11  12   OEE   EG  A  2  O
12  13   CAE   EG  A  2  C
13  14  HA1E   EG  A  2  H
14  15  HA2E   EG  A  2  H
15  16   CBE   EG  A  2  C
16  17  HB1E   EG  A  2  H
17  18  HB2E   EG  A  2  H
18  12   OEE   EG  A  3  O
19  13   CAE   EG  A  3  C
20  14  HA1E   EG  A  3  H
21  15  HA2E   EG  A  3  H
22  16   CBE   EG  A  3  C
23  17  HB1E   EG  A  3  H
24  18  HB2E   EG  A  3  H
25  12   OEE   EG  A  4  O
26  13   CAE   EG  A  4  C
27  14  HA1E   EG  A  4  H
28  15  HA2E   EG  A  4  H
29  16   CBE   EG  A  4  C
30  17  HB1E   EG  A  4  H
31  18  HB2E   EG  A  4  H
32  18  HB2E   EG  A  2  H
33  19    OE  EGH  A  3  O
34  20    CA  EGH  A  3  C
35  21   HA1  EGH  A  3  H
36  22   HA2  EGH  A  3  H
37  23    CB  EGH  A  3  C
38  24   HB1  EGH  A  3  H
39  25   HB2  EGH  A  3  H
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is not exactly what I want, but I can edit my data manual. I want column ['F']= [4,5,5,5,5,5,5]

Comment: @Elsaid sorry I have to admit I haven't checked the result in detail. Maybe provide a more minimal example to improve clarity (only 4/5 lines as input)

Comment: It's no problem! can you explain the code a bit? as I want to add a number to another column but it does not work. say I wanna add x to column 'G'   [d.assign(G=d[G]+x)]